# Contents of a panel won't visually update within a given time, but will clear completely afterwards

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with a picturebox docked to fill the whole thing. On this form, I have a panel that is normally invisible and another picturebox; on the panel, I have a label and another panel with a label.

Here is what SHOULD happen when the user hovers over the second picturebox:

1. The picturebox's image changes and the first panel becomes visible, making the second panel and both labels visible too
2. The user clicks on the second label
3. The second label's OnClick handler makes the first label's text change and the second panel becomes invisible
4. A timer ticks for a few seconds
5. A code segment in the timer's OnTick handler causes the image in the second picturebox to change and the first panel to become invisible

Here is what DOES happen:

1. The picturebox's image changes and the first panel becomes visible, making the second panel and both labels visible too
2. The user clicks on the second label
3. The second label's OnClick handler sets the first label's text to a new string and sets the second panel's Visible property to false, BUT the second panel stays visible (although you can't interact with it) and the first label's text gets written on top of the old text
4. A timer ticks for a few seconds
5. A code segment in the timer's OnTick handler causes the image in the second picturebox to change and the first panel to become invisible

I've tried everything I can think of. I've called Invalidate, Update, and Refresh on every control in the form, I've called Application.DoEvents, I've reset the image in the background PictureBox to itself, nothing. The REALLY weird part is that in step 5, when the front picturebox resets itself and all panels are set invisible, nothing gets left behind - it's just for that brief few seconds between the OnClick handler terminating and the timer's OnTick cleaning up that there are problems. I can edit this for more information if needed, but does anyone have any ideas of what to do?

Edit: It's been pointed out to me that I should probably upload the code for this. Well, that code is a hacked-together mess, but okay. Also: there are some weird extra bits (in the enum types among others), they're for later parts of the project and irrelevant right now.

```
    bool CountingHoverTime = false;
    int HoverTime = 0;
    int MasterTick = 0;

    enum GhostState { Stand, Speak, Pet, Ask };
    GhostState curState;

    public enum TalkType { HoverGen, Petted, Spont, TimerMsg, Response };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        TopMost = true;
        ControlBox = false;
        Text = String.Empty;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;


        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent;

    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(curState == GhostState.Stand)
        {
            CountingHoverTime = true;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if((curState != GhostState.Ask) && (curState != GhostState.Stand))
        {
            MasterTick++;
            if(MasterTick > 10)
            {
                SetToBasic();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MasterTick = 0;
        }

        if (CountingHoverTime)
        {
            HoverTime++;
            if (HoverTime > 4)
            {
                HoverTime = 0;
                curState = GhostState.Ask;
                Say("What can I do for you?", TalkType.HoverGen);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetToBasic()
    {
        curState = GhostState.Stand;
        ghostBox.Image = Properties.Resources.stickStand1;
        TalkPanel.Visible = false;
    }

    public void Say(String speak, TalkType type)
    {
        mainText.Text = speak;
        if(type == TalkType.Response || type == TalkType.Spont)
        {
            curState = GhostState.Speak;
        }
        else
        {
            curState = GhostState.Ask;
        }
        ghostBox.Image = Properties.Resources.stickTalk;
        if (type == TalkType.HoverGen)
            OptionPanel.Visible = true;
        else
            OptionPanel.Visible = false;

        TalkPanel.Visible = true;
        backBox.Image = Properties.Resources.background;
        ghostBox.Invalidate();
        TalkPanel.Invalidate();
        mainText.Invalidate();
        backBox.Invalidate();
        ghostBox.Update();
        TalkPanel.Update();
        mainText.Update();
        backBox.Update();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    private void op1label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curState = GhostState.Speak;
        OptionPanel.Visible = false;
        Say("No can do yet.", TalkType.Response);
    }
```

Edit 2: I've put together a gif visualization of what's happening, thank you HandbagCrab.

[image: This is a demonstration of what's going wrong.]

Comment: Can you upload the code.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `backBox` from the Form and just setting the Form `BackgroundImage` property to your `Properties.Resources.background`? I can only assume from the description that the PictureBox forming the background is causing this odd effect.

Comment: Side note: Get rid of that `Application.DoEvent();` and never use it again.

Comment: @HandbagCrab, I have. It didn't work, and in fact caused the panel text never to disappear at all. Also, I need the PictureBox there because it lets the user click through the form, because the background image is just a blank canvas.

Comment: @LarsTech It sure as hell wasn't my first idea, but when I was researching ways to get around this kind of issue it was one of the things that came up, and by that point I was desperate enough to try anything.

Comment: You are complaining about something not happening when a user clicks on a label.  We con't see that code.

Comment: Right, sorry. Missed that. Added it now.

Comment: In your description you say the first labels text gets written over the old text. Are you adding a new label on top of the existing label? or using a custom paint event here? It might be worth running your application and using [Screen to Gif](https://www.screentogif.com/) to record what's happening.

Comment: @HandbagCrab How would I upload that anyway?

Comment: Do do any drawing? If not, chances are you need none of these invalidate, refresh ezv.. Can you break (with the debugger) during the delay to see what is going on? most likely the ui is tied up.

Comment: Have you tryed to call the Refresh() method after the Update()?

Comment: @KimLage Yes, I have. No success.

Comment: When you edit your question there's an image button at the top. Press it and then drag an image over the window that appears, just make sure it's less than 2mb.

Comment: Do you have a while true loop somewhere in your code?

Comment: @LarsTech I do not. Closest thing I have is a ticking timer that's enabled by default, that has an OnTick method (as you can see above.)

Comment: Why is everything transparent?

Comment: @LarsTech Because that's the point of this application - the user should only be able to interact with what's printed, and it should be able to sit "on top" of everything else but still be click-through.

Comment: Winforms isn't good at transparency.  You didn't document that.

Comment: @LarsTech I went ahead and added the code I used for transparency. The blank PictureBox is for clickthrough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've approached this from a different direction. I think the issue is to do with the picturebox you have docked on the form causing some issues.

To fix it and still keep the transparency, get rid of the `backBox`. Set the background colour of the form to a colour you're not going to use then set the transparency key to that colour. This will make those areas of the form transparent. Now you just need your hidden panel and your labels and whatever control it is that hosts your stick man image.

[image: Form setup]

I've left the backgrounds of the labels as pink here but you should change them to your background colour so that they're not transparent.

When I run the form I get the transparency still and when clicking on the grey panel (I've used a panel to simulate your stick man) shows the hidden panel with the labels. Clicking label2 updates the text on label1 (the one that contains the text "longish text"), completely replacing the text.

Here it is in use (I've not done a gif as I wanted each step to be clearly visible)

Here's the application when open:

[image: In Action 1]

Here it is after clicking the grey box:

[image: After clicking the grey box]

Here's the updated text when clicking label2:

[image: After clicking label 2]

I've left the application border style as Sizeable just so you can see where the border lies. I also took the screenshots over a black background so there was no visual clutter.

Here's me right clicking the desktop through the transparent section:

[image: Right clicking through the transparent section]

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Transparent it may be, but I can't click through it to anything sitting below it. I CAN click through any blank space on a PictureBox, which is why I had one sitting in the background in my design.

Comment: The form I created in the answer has no issues clicking things through the transparent section. You must have something else going on.

Comment: When I recreate it brand-new, your solution works perfectly fine. I dunno what changed in mine, or where along the line it did so, but if it's THIS weird then I'm just going to burn that trash heap to the ground and start fresh. Thank you!